# My AVD will not run my app

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I was testing my app in my AVD and the AVD no longer uploads the apk to the device. It used to work and I have reinstalled eclipse and the android SDK but it does'nt run the app. Any Suggestions to get it working???

Comment: in console/terminal, run the command `adb devices` while the EMU is running. Do you see the EMU listed as a running device?

Comment: check wheter ADB making connection with eclipse or nt

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround, but a little bit more work, well for me i think its good, after u run/build on eclipse, there is an apk file in the /bin folder. I used to copy that .apk over there to my microsd and install and reinstall for comparison when you are on the go.

Comment: I got it to work, it randomly started working again. Thanks though.